# Вывод данных модели в json без foreach

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord, php7

Пишу в контроллере:

```
$artists = Artist::find()->select("artist_id as id, name")->all();
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
return $artists;
```

В модели добавил несуществующее в БД поле id.

```
public $id;
```

Ожидаю увидеть вот такой результат:

```
[{"id":1234,"name":"artist name"}, ......]
```

Вижу вот такой:

```
[{"name":"artist name"}, ......]
```

Если получать id так, то выводится.

```
echo $artists[0]->id; // 1234
```

Что я делаю не так, почему в json не попадает artist_id as id?

Yii version 2.0.9
PHP version 7.0.8
Operating system    Debian 7

Comment: Конечно же, я могу через foreach подготовить массив для json, но совершенно этого не хочется делать.

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/12019#issuecomment-235246760

Answer (score 1):

На github подсказали код, котрый решил проблему.

```
$artists = Artist::find()->select("artist_id as id, name")->asArray(true)->all();
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
return $artists;
```